# Ruby on Rails Associations clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm starting out with the whole (wonderful) idea of database associations in Rails but I'm having problems because I'm working with an existing database that does not conform to Rails standards and cannot figure out how to name the associations. There are a couple of similar posts, but I can't wrap my head around the naming for my particular situation which is as follows:

```
table book with book.formatId looks up values in book_format.id
```

So foreign key book.formatId

My models are named: Book and BookFormat (I read that you use camelCase when your tables are separated by underscore).

Under the Book model I have this:

```
has_one :bookFormat, :foreign_key => 'book_format.id' # not sure if this format table.field is correct or I have to use something else here. Also not sure about the bookFormat, should it be BookFormat or bookformat?
```

The BookFormat model has this:

```
belongs_to :book
```

But when I try to do

```
book = Book.first
book.bookFormat.empty?
```

I get an error of method not found for bookFormat. So obviously something's wrong, but I can't figure out where.

A second part of the question is the use of many to many relationships. Example:

Tables
book, book_subjects, book_subjects2title

book_subjects.id => book_subjects2title.pId
book.id => book_subjects2title.bookId

I'm reading the Beginning Rails 3 book from Apress (which is a great book) but it's not very clear on all this or I'm just not getting it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the book stores the formatId on it, you should use belongs_to, and change the foreign key as such:

```
belongs_to :book_format, :class_name => 'BookFormat', :foreign_key => 'formatId'
```

For the table name, i did some quick searching, and found the following method: `set_table_name`

So you should be able to add it at the top of your model, like so:

```
 class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   set_table_name 'book'
   # the rest of book model code
 end

 class BookFormat < ActiveRecord::Base
   set_table_name 'book_format'
   # rest of book_format model code
 end
```

Normally rails uses plural table names, so hence why you need to specify it there.

Comment: I'll try your suggestions, but just wanted to say that to combat the plurals that rails uses you put this into the config/application.rb file: `config.active_record.pluralize_table_names = false` and that works without having to explicitly set the table names. At leas Book.first works so it is querying the right table.

Comment: I've done as you suggested, but I'm still getting the method not found error. So to clarify, `belongs_to :book_format` (book_format is the name of the table, yes?), 

Then wen I use the call book.bookformat.empty? is it BoookFormat, book_format or bookformat? What exactly do I use here?

Comment: I'm still quite confused as to where to use the table names and where to use the class names, also why do we use the class names in lowercase if they are actually created in uppercase. I know that if you follow rails guidelines and have it create the tables for you everything seems to work better, but that is, unfortunately, not an option for me I have to wrestle with an existing database.

Comment: Through more messing around I found out that the class will indeed have the methods, but the instantiated object will not. That is, `Book.first.book_format` will work, but `book = Book.first`, `book.book_format` will not. It would be great if I could figure out why and how to make it work.

Comment: Whoops. My answer should of included the table names as plural, but setting that config option would fix that. The belongs_to :symbol_here represents the Class name of the model in camel_casing format. Not the table. In this case, it was a matter of setting the model name correctly i believe, which i assumed to be BookFormat :)

Answer (score 0):

agmcleod put me on the right track, so here's the full answer in the hopes that this helps other people with similar problems:

I created the model with a different name for easier reading. So model Books will have:

```
class Books < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'bookpedia'
  belongs_to :format, :foreign_key => 'formatId' # we need to specify the foreign key because it is not the rails default naming
  has_many :author2title, :foreign_key => 'bookId'
  has_many :author, :through => :author2title
end
```

model Format:

```
class Format < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name 'book_format'
    has_many :books
end
```

Then an instance of the class will have the format method:

```
@book = Books.first
@book.format # Hardcover
```

For many to many relationships I'll paste the syntax here as well since that took me a while to figure out:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name 'book_author'
    has_many :author2title, :foreign_key => 'pId' # junction table
    has_many :books, :through => :author2title # establishing the relationship through the junction table
end
```

This is the actual junction table:

```
class Author2title < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name 'book_author2title'
    belongs_to :author, :foreign_key => 'pId' # foreign key needs to be here as well
    belongs_to :books, :foreign_key => 'bookId'
end
```

The book model above has the necessary entries for this many to many relationship already in it.

If anyone needs clarification on this I'd be happy to oblige since I struggled for more than a day to figure this out so would be glad to be of help.

Cheers.